1999 Toyota 4Runner transmission and headlight wiring question
I recently bought this 1999 toyota 4runner has 375,000 miles and the headlights had LED strips added which is nice but the regular headlights do not work.
Must use high beams to make lights come on at all.  But an odd side effect, when high beam lever is on high, the range lights?  P is barely on, R is fully on, D is faintly on and the transmission slips.  will not go above 20mph.  didnt know until yesterday going from high beams to regular let the transmission work.
Now it did not do this when I got it, we drove it at night this way just fine.  It sat for a week somewhere and could have been tampered with.
Since getting it running batt was dead, got it going and drove at night and could not go above 20 mph. so just sitting there a week? this happens.  I immediately ask the seller who says he has no idea about any transmission issue.
Now hope to find wiring info about the transmission, where do those cables go? Assume into the ecu only but now dont know; and how is the high/low beam doing this;  the owner had wired in LED lights and some stereo and added wires.
I used to work at a stereo shop and fixed problems, people splice in to most anything, connect and if it seems to have power, go with it.  from the fuse box and relay box there are no spliced in wires.  Have yet to open the center console plastic, and didnt see any extra wires looking underneath but have not gone in under the dash, am not as gifted anymore and its a small truck. Hard to describe to someone look for any spliced in wires.
Finding the diagrams for the hi/lo beam, the range lights PRNDL2L1, how are 3 on at once?  and then the transmission slips.  Will be easy once the cause is known.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!
